# Sum product of two table by column matching

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I have two tables, first with currency and value and the second one with currency and x-rate.
by matching currency columns from two tables, I want to multiply and sum the values.

| Currency | value |
| --- | --- |
| EUR | 10 |
| GBP | 20 |
| CHF | 30 |
| EUR | 40 |
| GBP | 50 |

And the second one

| Currency | x_rate |
| --- | --- |
| EUR | 1 |
| GBP | 1.2 |
| CHF | 1.3 |

The result should be: `10*1 + 40*1 + 20*1.2 + 50*1.2 + 30*1.3 = 173`

Answer (score 2):

Use array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B6*TRANSPOSE(E2:E4)*(A2:A6=TRANSPOSE(D2:D4)))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$6)*INDEX($E$2:$E$4,MATCH($A$2:$A$6,$D$2:$D$4,0)))
```

Where $A$2:$B$6 is the first table and $D$2:$E$4 is the second table.[image]

Comment: Thank you guys you help me  a lot.
so if i understand correct, each time i need to match values in columns, for example, i need to use Index and Match function
If for example i want to sum instead of multiply, what should I do?

Comment: It multiplies the values to the x rates where the currency matches.